# How does ascii hexbin become 4 bit?

Tags: ascii

https://biorobotics.fi-p.unam.mx/wp-content/uploads/Courses/arquitectura_de_computadoras/material_de_apoyo/68HC11.pdf

In Buffalo Entry Points in HC11, there are these lines

[image]

I couldn't figure it out. Ascii hex are 7-bit with 127 numbers. How can it change into 4-bit?? What is it exactly doing?

Comment: It expects a hexadecimal digit encoded in ascii, i.e. anything between 0-9 and a-f (and/or A-F, no idea which cases it handles). That is only 4 bits (half a byte) worth of data.

Comment: Also what is SHFTREG? A character always contains hex character from 00 to FF. how could register A not contain a hex character?

Comment: If what you described was not based on my deleted example, but direct knowledge. What register did it put the binary number? what is SHFTREG, what address.. because it is not register A.

Comment: (last lines in orignal message deleted because I didn't use # but only % in ldaa. when I used #, it returns 00 to ff for original register A of 00 to ff. So it must be keeping the converted 4 bit binary elsewhere, where?

Answer (score 1):

Just for convenience a verbatim copy from the linked PDF:

```
.HEXBIN EQU     $FF85   ; = JMP HEXBIN
                        ; Convert ascii hex char in A to 4-bit binary number.
                        ; Shift binary number into SHFTREG from the right.
                        ; SHFTREG is a 2-byte (4 hex digits) buffer. If A
                        ; register did not contain a hex character, location
                        ; TMP1 is incremented and SHFTREG is unchanged.
```

I sorted your (sub-)questions in some subjective logical order...

> Ascii hex are 7-bit with 127 numbers.

Well, no. ASCII defines a 7-bit code for non-printable and printable characters, that's right. You can write these code in hex, but this is not meant here. You can choose any number base, not only hex, to write the codes.

What the author means are the characters we use for **hex digits**, and which are coded in ASCII, hence "*ASCII hex char*". These are '0' to '9' coded as $30 to $39, 'A' to 'F' coded as $41 to $46, and commonly also 'a' to 'f' coded as $61 to $66.

> A character always contains hex character from 00 to FF. how could register A not contain a hex character?

As you already said before, ASCII characters are only defined as 7-bit values. They range from $00 to $7F. However, there are *extended* ASCII character sets, but they differ at many codes.

Not all 8-bit values are ASCII codes for hex characters, only those I listed above. But you can express all 8-bit values by 2 hex characters. For these 2 hex characters you need 14 bits, commonly stored as 2 8-bit values.

> How can it change into 4-bit??

As the input to the routine is just one ASCII character, provided in register A, and interpreted as hex digit, the result is just the 4-bit value of the hex digit input character. Or none, if the character is no hex digit.

> If what you described was not based on my deleted example, but direct knowledge. What register did it put the binary number?

As the comment says, the result is shifted from the right into the RAM location `SHFTREG`.

> what is SHFTREG, what address.. because it is not register A.

> (last lines in orignal message deleted because I didn't use # but only % in ldaa. when I used #, it returns 00 to ff for original register A of 00 to ff. So it must be keeping the converted 4 bit binary elsewhere, where?

The return value of register A is not documented. You are right, `SHFTREG` is not the register A. Since the linked PDF lacks the definition of `SHFTREG`, I cannot say for sure. It is a 2-byte location most probably in RAM. Chapter 2.7 documents in table 2 the range of $0033 to $00FF as used for Buffalo. I'd assume it is somewhere there.

*Note: This is the deleted example:*

> I tried running FF85 in HC11. If A=04, it remains A=04 after running Ldaa #04, jmp $FF85. But if the ldaa is #65 for example, jmp FF85 will produce A=9A. How?

The prefix `#` marks a value as "immediate". Since you said above that you used `%` instead of `#`, I wonder that the assembler did not throw an error. The prefix `%` marks a binary literal, but you gave it non-binary digits. Without the `#` you wrote an instruction that loads A from a RAM location, not with a literal. Anyway, it is not really relevant, since you looked at the value of A after returning. But that is not documented and therefore tells us not much.

> What is it exactly doing?

This routine expects an ASCII coded character as a hex digit and decodes the value of the hex digit. The result is shifted from the right into `SHFTREG`, if the character is a hex digit. Else it does not change `SHFTREG`, but increments another RAM location labeled as `TMP1`.

| Input in A | 4-bit value shifted into `SHFTREG` | Action on `TMP1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '0' = $30 = 48 | $0 | none |
| : | : | : |
| '9' = $39 = 57 | $9 | none |
| 'A' = $41 = 65 | $A | none |
| : | : | : |
| 'F' = $46 = 70 | $F | none |
| 'a' = $61 = 97 | $A | none |
| : | : | : |
| 'f' = $66 = 102 | $F | none |
| any other | none | increment |